# Schedule a report to send email to different employees based on employee ids

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

My use case is similar to sending payslips.

That is, Jasper report should be scheduled in such a way that at the end of every month, it runs and sends payslips to different email ids based on the employee ids.

i.e, How can I make the JR server understand that send "abc" report to "abc@somedomain.com" and "pqr" report to "pqr@somedomain.com" where abc has employeeid as 123 and pqr has employeeid 456? How would I do this?

Comment: That is what I am wondering. How to do that? As you know, I am a beginner. Please guide me in detail.

Comment: This problem need the research and the time for this.

Answer (score 0):

I can pass on few inputs which might be helpful:

Design your report with input parameters accepting employeeId as input. Jasper Server has EmailNotifications options where you can pass on the email-ids.

Schedule your report using Rest-API's of Jasper Server. You can find my comment over here [Jasper Report with RestAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305093/jasper-report-with-restapi)